How to call one poetry environment from a different poetry environment
I have two different folders or locations. Let's call these "app" and "source". In the source folder there is a script.
The Previous situation
Before each folder had its own virtual environment (created with venv)
The app folder had a RestAPI script (written with FastAPI) that called a script from the source folder.
Obviously since the source virtual environment was different, it did something like
command = f'bash -c \'source {venv_path} && python3 {script_path} \' '

try:
        result = subprocess.run(command, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        # Return the output and the completion status
        return {
            "stdout": result.stdout,
            "stderr": result.stderr,
            "returncode": result.returncode,
            "status": "Completed" if result.returncode == 0 else "Error",
        }
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Error running script: {str(e)}")

which correctly run the script in the source folder with its own virtual environment python.
Now using Poetry
I have replaced the venvs with poetry. So now in source I have a pyproject.toml and poetry's virtual environment is working
In the app folder I also have a pyproject.toml and poetry's virtual environment is also working.
However, I can see that the app script calls the scripts in source with its own poetry environment and not source's envrionment.
I have tried first changing the directory in the command
command = f'cd {script_path.parent} && poetry run python {script_path.name} '

and then even
command = f'poetry run python {script_path.name} '

try:
        result = subprocess.run(command, cwd=source_dir, shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
        # Return the output and the completion status
        return {
            "stdout": result.stdout,
            "stderr": result.stderr,
            "returncode": result.returncode,
            "status": "Completed" if result.returncode == 0 else "Error",
        }
    except Exception as e:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=500, detail=f"Error running script: {str(e)}")

and still the app in the app folder tries to call the script in the source folder with its own poetry virtual environment.
Question
How can I make that app in the app folder calls the script located in source with the source poetry environment?

You should be able to create a [project.scripts] in your pyproject.toml file, which when installed into a venv, will create an executable in venv/bin. In that generated executable, there will be logic to source the virtual environment it belongs to via a shebang line #!/path/to/my/venv/bin/python, which runs the entrypoint using the python executable from that venv. You can then call this executable anywhere, without needing to source any venv yourself.

See https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/guides/writing-pyproject-toml/#creating-executable-scripts
